# Find two integers in a sorted array A[1..n] such that a = 3b - 7 in O(n) time and O(1) space

Tags: arrays, algorithm

A[1..n] has only positive elements.

I have one solution for O(n):

```
B = new Array()

for i=1 to n
    B[i] = 3A[i]-7

C = merge(A,B) such that C is also sorted

for i=1 to n-1
    if (C[i] == C[i+1])
        return TRUE

return FALSE
```

What would be the O(1) way to do it? 
By the way i have a (probably wrong) sketch, where it say that we can find it using two scanlines, but i dont understand that either.

Comment: Just so I understand the question, you're saying given an array {1,2,3,4,5}, you want to (a=2, b=3), because 3(3)-7 == 2 (or alternately find (a=5, b=4), since 3(4)-7 == 5)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scan the array from left to right, maintaining two pointers: one to the current candidate for `b` and one to the current candidate for `a`. Here is a pseudocode implementation (which also happens to be runnable Python):

```
def find(l):
  i, j = 0, 0
  while i < len(l) and j < len(l):
    b = l[i]
    a = 3 * b - 7
    while j < len(l) and l[j] < a:
      j += 1
    if j < len(l) and l[j] == a:
      return i, j
    i += 1
  return None

l = [1, 3, 5, 8, 10, 27, 45]
print find(l)
```

This is O(1) space and O(n) time (since it never looks at an element more than twice).

Answer (score 2):

Initialise two indices, i1 and i2, to the start of the sorted array.

Now loop:

Get the value at i1, and calculate 3b-7.

Now search forward from i2, until the value is >= the search value. If it is =, you have found the two integers. If it is > then advance i1 and loop around.

Comment: Does that run in `O(n)`? I think not.

Comment: @phant0m It's a simple linear search, so yes.

Comment: Well wouldn't it be O(n^2) because of the nested loop? According to your description, there are two loops. Could you perhaps write it in pdeusocode?

Comment: Actually, it would come out to O(2n), which is offically O(n), so, yes, it work.  Note that i2 isn't reset to zero, but always moves forward, so at worst, the array would be iterated through twice.

Comment: @JamesCurran In that case, I have not understood the description correctly.

Comment: @phant0m: Note that 3(n+1)-7 will always be greater than 3(n)-7 (given all positive numbers, which is a given in the problem), so once we've found the index of the value of 3n-7, we can start there when looking for 3(n+1)-7, so there's no "inner loop".

Comment: @JamesCurran Thanks, I just misread the `advance i1 and loop around` as `loop i1 around`, which implied an inner loop.